# How to retain formcollection values on postback in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Here I am using simple application and on clicking send button I will execute Index httppost action. But for some reason if my captcha is not correct then i am trying to load the same view. I am passing form collection so my firstname and lastname are not wiped out. Please suggest how can i persist my values.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(FormCollection dataColl)
        {
            ColComments datgrp = new ColComments();
            datgrp.fname = dataColl[0].ToString();
            datgrp.lname = dataColl[1].ToString();

            if (!this.IsCaptchaValid(""))
            {

                ViewBag.Classname = "alert alert-warning";
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Incorrect captcha answer.";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "OKAY";
                return RedirectToAction("Landing", "Account");
            }

            return View(dataColl);
        }
```

Index view.

```
@using CaptchaMvc.HtmlHelpers
@model CaptchaTestApp.Models.ColComments
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
    <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
    <p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>

</div>
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div> @Html.ValidationSummary(true)</div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>ColComments</legend>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fname)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fname)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fname)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lname)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lname)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lname)
                </div>
            </fieldset>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            @Html.Captcha(8, "_captchaCnt")
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <p>

                    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
                </p>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the same view which you are sending in HttpGet method with updated values. You are sending form collection object to view.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(FormCollection dataColl)
        {
            ColComments datgrp = new ColComments();
            datgrp.fname = dataColl[0].ToString();
            datgrp.lname = dataColl[1].ToString();

            if (!this.IsCaptchaValid(""))
            {

                ViewBag.Classname = "alert alert-warning";
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Incorrect captcha answer.";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "OKAY";
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return View(datgrp);
        }
```

Comment: I am using captchaMVC and on `IsCaptchaValid("")` I am getting A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client error. That's because lname field has html content `lname="<p>Test</p>"` How can I fix this error

Comment: you have two options to solve this 1. add `[AllowHtml]` attributes on model property lname. 2. Add `[ValidateInput(false)]` on controller POST method

Comment: I did that `[ValidateInput(false)]` but I am still getting `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client error` at `IsCaptchaValid("")`

Comment: Is it going inside the POST method or throwing error before that?

Comment: Its going inside post method but the erro is thrown at this line `if (!this.IsCaptchaValid(""))`

Comment: Check and  verify if you have tried all these solutions https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Solution-ASPNet-MVC-A-potentially-dangerous-RequestForm-value-was-detected-from-the-client.aspx

Comment: Its better then to post this as separate question, you will definitely get the solution

Comment: Thanks Arun Sure will do! Appreciate your help